# Build Phonegap 3.1 app locally for android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I started PhoneGap today only. I have experience with native code but not with HTML5 stuff. I am comfortable with GUI so CLI is new to me.
So I am trying to build app in android. But it uploads data to remote site  & as its my second app, Its says "Private app limit reached".
Is there any way to build file locally?? Like with no internet connection. Screenshot attached for further refrence. [image]Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [Android platform guide section](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) of the PhoneGap documentation you'll get instructions for setting up your SDK locally.

Pay attention so that you got your `PATH` setup correctly, a quick way to verify that on windows is to type `echo %PATH%` in the command prompt. If you already had your command prompt open as you set PATH it'll not be reflected so you've to close cmd and open it again.

After the SDK is setup successfully and you got your `PATH` verified you should be able to do the following to run it:

```
phonegap install android
phonegap local build android
phonegap local run android --emulator
```